# Unable to load CSS and images from the Content folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7.5

I have placed CSS and images in the Content folder.

**All works fine in VS2010,** but when I deployed to IIS 7.5, I am unable to load CSS and image files from the Content folder. But I can load scripts from Content\Scripts. If I put the files in the root folder, however, I am able to access.

I have done the following:

- Make sure IIS has the serve static content role
- Make sure the mapping
  for static file exists
- Add the IIS_USR permission to the folder
  (application and both Content)
- Making sure to use absolute URL i.e.
  `@<link href = "@Url.Content("~/content/style.css")" rel="stylesheet"
  type = "text/css" media="screen"/>`

Those do not fix the problem.

What else can I do?

Comment: View HTML source in browser and see what the actual generated URLs are, and then try open the links in the source in a new tab.

Comment: I get file not found. However, the JS files, which are included in the same manner, can be retrieved.

Comment: Is this the same as adding the role service? http://gurustop.net/blog/2009/10/12/funny-problem-windows-7-iis-7-5-images-css-not-showing/

Comment: Yes, a 404. When I try to access the folder, I get a 403

Comment: I can't answer because it's only a vague memory but I seem to remember having this problem where IIS would not serve up plain content. I also don't remember how I fixed it. I think I just re-installed IIS from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was another virtual folder in the site called Content.

We changed the name of the virtual path and the content loaded properly.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/styles.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Nope, I was already doing that, fixed the typo in my question.